# Remove Woocommerce action from external plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm switching to a new Wordpress plugin I've written myself that will run along side an old plugin on top of the Woocommerce cart. While I'm running the two plugins I want to remove the old plugin's action that calls it's table to display in the users my account page. I will be adding logic after to work out if it's needed, but for now I just need to remove it.

This is how the action is being called in the old plugin.

```
class WC_Subscriptions {

 public static function init() {

  // Display Subscriptions on a User's account page
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', __CLASS__ . '::get_my_subscriptions_template' );      

 }

}

WC_Subscriptions::init();
```

So far in my own plugin I have called the following and none of them work.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array('WC_Subscriptions', 'get_my_subscriptions_template' ) );
// no error but still shows the table
```

and the last one

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( WC_Subscriptions::init(), 'get_my_subscriptions_template' ) );   
// Fatal error: Class 'WC_Subscriptions' not found in /var/sites/XXXXX on line 45
```

I have tried changing/adding the `$priority` from 1, 9, 10, 11 and 99 and that doesn't work either.

It's frustrating as I'm sure it would work if the old plugin was initiated with a `new` instance so I could do this

```
global $my_class;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( $my_class, 'get_my_subscriptions_template' ) );
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This always happens, just worked it out.
I needed to hook the remove_action into another action that is called much later.

In the end I did this

```
class My_new_plugin {

 public function __construct() {
  add_action( 'wp_head', array($this, 'remove_action_woosubscription_table' ) );        
 }

 public function remove_action_woosubscription_table() {
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( 'WC_Subscriptions', 'get_my_subscriptions_template' ) );   
 }

}
```

Comment: As you've found you need to remove the action *after* `WC_Subscriptions` has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can set third attribute 'priority' as 999

```
 <?php remove_action( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority ); ?>
```